# How do I change the number of kernels that stay on boot menu?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I'm having an issue with the current kernel and was recommended to install the newest mainline kernel. However, with only two kernel boot options (3.2.0-24 and 3.2.0-25) I'm afraid I'll lose the working v3.2.0-24 if I install the mainline Debian package.

Where can I set how many back-kernels are left on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the mainline kernel does not remove the previous ones (it shouldn't by default) by replacing them (and as I said it shouldn't normally do that), you previous kernels will remain intact.

You can manage the number of kernels you have by adding or removing kernels via the package manager. You can also set limits in grub I believe (but I don't remember off hand, so I would have to update my answer).

Comment: So, it appears I'm an idiot lol. I've always just looked at the linux-image-generic package. Never realized it was a meta-package... I always wondered why the number of installed kernels dropped from like 3-4 to 2, guess it was just a dependency change in the linux-image-generic metapackage.